# React Native Bottom Sheet - Avoiding Keyboard

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm having some problems trying to make the bottom sheet to respond based on the size of the content. My bottom sheet needs to have a fixed input on the bottom and 2 positions - 50% and 90%. On 50% the bottom sheet needs to be pushed when the keyboard appears and on 90% the content of my flat list needs to be pushed up. Is possible to achieve this?

Steps To Achieve
On 50% - bottom sheet needs to be pushed up until the max size(90%)

on 90% - the flat list inside needs to be pushed up

[image]

Comment: oh god this topic is so ugly in rn because each case is diferent and customized depends on diferent things, did you try a solution whit https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.67/keyboardavoidingview?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the library [react-native-bottom-sheet](https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet). It is very customizable and has some components that handle the keyboard automatically.